# Cleaning the post array?

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox, mysql-real-escape-string

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to add in precautions to my web form to avoid misuse, these inputs from the user are being stored to a database. I keep getting errors when trying to pass through the whole post array. I believe its to do with the checkboxes.

I have a function below:

```
function CleanArray($array) {

        return array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array);
}
```

I also have 2 input fields and a bunch of multiple check boxes.

Example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="decks[]" value="All Decks"/>
  <label>All Decks</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="decks[]" value="Competitor"/>
  <label>Competitor</label>
```

Now when I execute this code it flags up an error and wont output the multiple checkbox values (I have selected several).

```
$_POST = CleanArray($_POST);
```

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string,

So I decided to unset the the problem bit from the array, then clean it separately and add it back in the array. This works and I get all the data I need. I feel this is a lot of effort and is it really needed?

```
    $decks = $_POST['decks'];
    unset($_POST['decks']);
    $_POST = CleanArray($_POST);
    $decks = CleanArray($decks);
    $_POST['decks'] = $decks;
```

My output:

> hello
>   hello
>   All Decks,Competitor,Misc,Partners and stakeholders,Process,Product,Structures and Roles

Any advice would be appreciated. I feel this is rooky error and maybe I don't understand the function enough.

Thanks
Hayley

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`. See the big red notice about `mysql_` being deprecated at http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string? Look into PDO with bound parameters.

Comment: The best thing you can do is **not** use the obsolete `mysql_` extension, move to `pdo` or `mysqli` - then you can use prepared statements with bound parameters and all your sanitisation woes will disappear

Comment: before you go any further with this you should know that mysql_* driver has been deprecated, which mean mysql_real_escape_string is as well. you really need to use PDO or MySQLi instead. I recommend you find a new tutorial or book to study from as whatever you're using is obviously outdated.

Comment: You really ought to switch to PDO or mysqli, as mysql_* functions have been deprecated, and removed completely from PHP7. If you use one of those libraries properly by binding your variables, then you won't have to clean it up yourself.

Comment: idk if anyone mentioned it yet but mysql_ functions are deprecated, btw

Comment: also, mysql_ funcitons have been deprecated.

Comment: @PootieTang ha! at least i was first? ;-)

Comment: Stop. mysql_* is deprecated. Use PDO instead and you don't have to worry about it by using prepared statements.

Comment: Ye i noticed, I was following a tutorial on securing form inputs.
Can anyone recommend a good source?

Comment: Could someone suggest how I would rewrite the function in PDO or does the query handling do all this for me?

Comment: You won't need the function at all with PDO - but you will need to completely rewrite your database interface : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php